# Second ODE problems

Tags: calculus

I need some help with this question:

A ride at the Lune Park amusement park consists of a carriage mounted on the top of a spring, as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

The bottom of the spring is fixed to the ground. The carriage (loaded with its passenger) has a mass of 150kg. The carriage can only move vertically. The natural length of the spring is 10 m and its spring constant is $k = 600 N/m$. At equilibrium the spring is compressed by a distance $s$ metres. Air resistance acts on the carriage with a drag coefficient $300 Ns/m$. Assume that the gravitational constant is $g = 10$ $m/s^2.$

The ride begins with the carriage released from rest $0.5 m$ above ground level.

Let $y(t)$ be the height of the carriage below its equilibrium position at time t seconds after the ride begins. Take the positive direction to be downwards.

(a) Draw a diagram of the ride when the system is in equilibrium, and a diagram of the ride when the carriage is below its equilibrium and moving up. Show all forces acting on the carriage and label them with their magnitudes.

(b) The equation of motion for this system is
$$150y'' + 300y' + 600y = 0$$
(You do not need to derive this equation.) Solve the equation of motion to find $y(t)$.

(c) Find an expression for the height $h(t)$ of the carriage above ground level at time t.

(d) Sketch the graph of $h(t)$ versus t.

I need help with part (c) and (d). I solved the equation in part (b) and got $7e^{-t}cos \sqrt3t$ + $7 \over {\sqrt 3}$$e^{-t}sin \sqrt 3t$

I'm really stuck on how to continue with part c and d. Could I get some advice please?

Comment: $y$ is the hight above equilibrium position, $h$ is the height above ground. You only need to compute the equilibrium position... Use [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law): at which height does the spring force equilibrate the weight?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but is it 0.25m?

Comment: does h(t)=7.5 -y?

Comment: At equilibrium, you have $600\times x=150\times10$, hence $x=2.5m$, (where $x$ is the distance from spring equilibrium), hence the carriage is at $7.5m$ above ground at equilibrium. At $t=0$ in the ODE solution, you have $y=7$, thus $h=7.5-y$ is correct. Quick check: $y$ is initially decreasing, so $h$ is increasing, as it should (the spring is compressed, so it will go up when released).